# ¿Como puedo integrar Google Maps en Laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, google-maps, google-api

Estoy en el desarrollo de una pagina web la cual esta desarrollada en PHP - Laravel 
Necesito integrar Google Maps (Inputs que me muestren las direcciones y el mapa con la direccion) mediante cdn o descargando las librerías con los estilos y los JS debido a que mi servidor es remoto y no conozco una manera de hacer un update mediante composer o algo así en el servidor hosting

¿Alguien sabe de que manera pueda integrar dicho elemento?

Comment: Cuando dice las direcciones te refieres a los puntos de gotas desplazados por el mapa?. Bueno saltando a tu pregunta debes registrarte en cloud google y adquirir la api de mapas, donde te estregaran una key que incrustarlas en tu archivo php en la cabecera con una etiquete <script> para luego poder jugar con todas las herramientas del mapa de google, desde colocar puntos hasta realizar trazados en el mapa.

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy realizando el proceso con mi jefe para realizar la compra de la API cuando la obtengamos y la implemente te comentare que sucede

Comment: Otra alternativa es usar Mapas de ArcGis esto no cobran y son parecidos a google, pero los de google son mas estéticos y actualizados.

Comment: Entiendo, le daré una revisada a la API que me dices, porque siempre es importante el costo relación. Gracias por tu aporte! cualquier cosa te comentare

Comment: Esta bien,saludos :)